# What counts towards the 500-item limit in firestore batch writes?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in a cloud function which is returning an error with the message

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: maximum 500 writes allowed per request

```
console.log(`${projectId} doClassifySources: Got ${_.size(output)} items`)

const lastClassification = new Date().toJSON()
const batch = firestore.batch()
batch.update(projectRef, {lastClassification})
_.forEach(output, item => {
  batch.set(projectRef.collection('output').doc(encodeURIComponent(item.url)), {
    classifiedAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    ...item
  }, {
    merge: true
  })
})

return batch.commit().then(() => lastClassification)
```

Yet the firebase logs show this right before the error is thrown:

```
12:28:19.963 PM classifySources ZklZYB5hq96J43CroKgP doClassifySources: Got 310 items
```

That looks to me like the batch should contain 310 items, well below the 500 limit. Am I missing something in how that 500-item limit is calculated? Does the `merge: true` influence that in any way? Is it to do with the spread of `item` in the object being written (i.e. does that increase the number of writes needed)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With some additional testing, it appears that using `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` counts as an extra 'write'. With the code as above, I'm limited to 249 items (i.e. when `output.length >= 250`, the code will fail with that error message. If I remove the reference to `serverTimeStamp()`, I can get up to 499 items per write.

I can't find this documented anywhere, and perhaps it is a bug in the firebase library, so I will post an issue there and see what happens.

Comment: Github issue with slightly simplified code: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/408 In my original, the first `batch.update()` obviously counts as a single write, so that's why I was getting 249 not 250 as the cutoff.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was scratching my head wondering why a 400 documents insert batch was triggering the 500 limit on my Android Kotlin app. I am also using `ServerTimestamp` on the docs, and your answer explains the error. BTW, why don't you accept your own answer?

Comment: Thanks—have now. I think I was waiting to see if there was anything concrete emerging from the firebase issues on github other than proposed documentation updates, and then was ... oh look, squirrel.